# C# compiler not showing complete stack trace for runtime errors

Tags: c#, mono, stack-trace

C# compiler version:

```
mono --version

Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Debian 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

```
dmcs --version

Mono C# compiler version 4.2.1.0
```

I am running the following piece of code:

`DriverCode.cs`:

```cs
using System;

public class DriverCode
{
        public static void Main(String[] a)
        {
            Solution sol = new Solution();
            sol.test(0);
        }
}
```

`Solution.cs`:

```cs
public class Solution 
{
    public int test(int x) 
    {
        return f1(x);
    }

    public int f1(int x) 
    {
        return 1/x;
    }
}
```

I compiled and run code as:

```sh
dmcs -debug -target:exe -warn:0 -out:DriverCode.exe -r:System.Web.Extensions.dll -recurse:*.cs

mono --debug DriverCode.exe
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
  at DriverCode.Main (System.String[] a) [0x00007] in /home/ucl/data/csharp/DriverCode.cs:7
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
  at DriverCode.Main (System.String[] a) [0x00007] in /home/ucl/data/csharp/DriverCode.cs:7
```

The above runtime error is giving the correct line number for `DriverCode.cs` but I am not getting any info for `Solution.cs` file. How can I get complete error? Is there any way to enable detailed error or enable complete stacktrace for error? Like we get in java.
Or it is a limitation for the c# compiler.

**Note:** I know I am using too old version. But this is something which I can not update and needed to support old version too.

Comment: In short, you should use .NET 6 now, not Mono, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-mono/

Comment: The debug info is in the pdb file.  So the dll doesn't have a pdb file or you are using the release folder instead of the debug folder for the 2nd project.

Comment: @LexLi I understand that but I needed to support that in my application.